# Windows display fluctuates automatically between "Project to a connected screen" options

Tags: windows-8.1, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, nvidia-graphics-card, intel-graphics

The display switches automatically between "PC Screen Only" & "Extend" modes options from "Project to a connected screen" options, which are visible to me and <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>. Earlier it used to be the "Duplicate" option.

The switch happens most often whenever the Ethernet port or a charger is used, but not restricted to anything specific I could note.

This starts with a screen shaking followed by a blank screen, then the automatic switching; worse, the system gets slow.

I have re-installed and updated both Intel & NVIDIA drivers, but to no good.

This has been a problem for the last 2 months. I am not very familiar with the internals of a Windows system, so this might be a naive problem, but I couldn't find a solution with Google search.

How to fix this?

System: Acer Aspire V5-571G; Windows 8.1 64-bit; Intel(R) HD Graphics 3000; NVIDIA GeForce GT 620M

**Update:** I **formatted my laptop fully today**, due to display going black at every start, just after displaying logos. **But as it stands now, the problem is still here**. This is making me mad now. Can someone atleast respond with a guess now? Virus, hardware, more specific anything... Something I could possibly ask a technician to look into! Please.

Comment: I couldn't find a solution and neither could the service guys, but apparently, they have located the problem to be related to the Motherboard (graphics & network cards). So, not much anybody could have done here, but thanks anyways!